# Timestamped android:label

Tags: android, android-manifest

For development & debug purposes, I would like to have the label under the icon contain a timestamp that hints when this particular instance was built.

The entry that's responsible for this label is `android:label="@string/app_name"` under the main activity.

The problem is that `@string/app_name` is hard-coded.

Is is possible at all to accomplish a build timestamped label as I described above?

I don't mind setting it in onCreate() (i.e. will change after the 1st run), as long as it indeed changes the label **under the icon** (not in the title bar).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you should do is include a step in your build process that always modifies the `app_name` xml value to include the time stamp. This can be done with Ant using an [XML Mainpulation Task to replace xml value](http://today.java.net/pub/a/today/2006/11/01/xml-manipulation-using-xmltask.html#replacing-xml).

Comment: Thanks +1 for this great tip. Unfortunately, I am using Eclipse, not Ant. Is there a way to do this on Eclipse, too?

Comment: yea, checkout this blogpost: http://www.androidengineer.com/2010/06/using-ant-to-automate-building-android.html